# Fluid - "pancakes" instead of flow

Tags: fluid-simulation

I did the usual water simulation, resolution divisions is 100, initial velocity on normal is 15 (extra fluid speed). I wanted to get usual flow, but I have this (picture). How to fix it?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably has to do with the timestep rate. The fluid is moving so fast that the timesteps are too little in order to accurately capture the motion, causing the "broken apart" effect you are having.

Just go into the simulation settings and bump up the "maximum timesteps" value.